# How do I save a video file in SAP HANA?

Tags: video, hana, .mov

I need to be able to save a .MOV file in HANA and then access it to be displayed on an HTML page.  I can't find any resources out there to help with this issue.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There's no special video or streaming data type available in SAP HANA.
You may simply store the video file in a BLOB column and retrieve it from there.

However, be aware that there is - again - no streaming support. Your web-page needs to read the whole file out of the database and hand it to the web-player.